# xConnect - 'Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model, 8.3' does not match the remote version

Tags: xconnect

I am trying to make a call from Sitecore 9 rev 170622 (Tech Preview) to an xConnect of 9 rev 171002 (IR). During the initialization I am getting the following error:

One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer. 'Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model, 8.3' does not match the remote version

Here is my full code:

```
CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions options =
CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions.Parse("StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=0D80A21AAF0A3B76B87C5E2AA0FCF78C18252259B");

var certificateModifier = new CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier(options);

List<IHttpClientModifier> clientModifiers = new List<IHttpClientModifier>();
var timeoutClientModifier = new TimeoutHttpClientModifier(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
clientModifiers.Add(timeoutClientModifier);

var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://xp0.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://xp0.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("xp0.xconnect/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

var cfg = new XConnectClientConfiguration(
new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);

try
{
  cfg.Initialize(); // HERE IS WHERE THE CODE BREAKS
}
catch (XdbModelConflictException ce)
{
Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + ce.Message);
return View();
}

using (var client = new XConnectClient(cfg))
{
var results0 = client.Contacts.ToEnumerable().Count();
}
```

Does anyone know what this is about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default collection model in the Tech Preview was versioned as `8.3`.  In the initial release, it became `9.0`.  So, the Tech Preview instance of Sitecore is not using the same version of the model as xConnect is using.

I would imagine there are a number of other changes that were made between the Tech Preview and the initial release that would cause issues...

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason! However I'm here thinking to myself: since xConnect is supposed to be used to get and set content from external platforms, shouldn't it be able to connect no matter what version it is? I mean, if we were using only a command prompt to query xConnect, the command prompt itself has no collection models (I know we can create new models and extend that) - so why would that matter?

Anyhow, I am installing a second instance of Sitecore 9 IR to continue my research.

Comment: You're attempting to connect to xConnect from a client (SC9 TP) that has loaded a version of the collection model that xConnect knows nothing about.  Theoretically, if you had a copy of the _8.3 version_ of the collection model (in `json` format) in the `<xconnect-server-path>\App_data\Models` folder, you would probably be ok.

Comment: Sounds right Jason, thank you very much. I will install a second 9IR instance to have that working then. See ya!